# HTML Input[Date] defaulting to mm/dd/yyyy despite locale settings

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, date, input

I am using a html date input in an `ng-repeat` scenario, and it seems to default to `mm/dd/yyyy` despite my computer regional settings being set to `dd/mm/yyyy`.

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app>
    <input class="form-control" type="date" ng-model="attendee.Dob"/>
</body>
```

Is there an easy way to re-format this? I can't seem to find anything that works, as everything suggests that the `<input>` element should use my local datepicker settings.

Sorry if I have missed something here.

Comment: Relying on browsers to observe regional settings for formatting is fraught, just don't do it. Even if it worked reliably for a wide range of languages, you're depending on the user setting it appropriately. Far better to use an unambiguous format (e.g. 27 Jan 2020) and leave it at that. Even attempting to use the default language is fraught, as there is no standard for setting it or the languages that need to, or must, be supported by implementations.

Comment: Thanks @RobG. Do you have any examples of how to best implement this then?

Comment: No, though you might try airline and travel booking sites, though I hate sites that don't let me input the date using the keyboard. My focus is on usability and unambiguity. Localisation of format leads down a rabbit hole of complexity with no end and the default HTML date input is virtually worthless for the reasons given on MDN. There are a huge number of libraries, plugins, widgets, etc. for doing the job. I can't recommend one here, just search and pick one. If you have issues, post again. :-)

Answer (score 1):

From the Docs:

> Date inputs sound convenient — they provide an easy interface for choosing dates, and they normalize the data format sent to the server regardless of the user's locale. However, there are currently issues with `<input type="date">` because of its limited browser support.
>
> Unsupporting browsers gracefully degrade to a text input, but this creates problems in consistency of user interface (the presented controls are different) and data handling.
>
> The second problem is the more serious one; with date input supported, the value is normalized to the format `yyyy-mm-dd`. But with a text input, the browser has no recognition of what format the date should be in, and there are many different formats in which people write dates.
>
> At the moment, the best way to deal with dates in forms in a cross-browser way is to have the user enter the day, month, and year in separate controls, or to use a JavaScript library such as jQuery date picker.

For more information, see

- [MDN HTML Reference - `<input type="date">` Browser Support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Handling_browser_support)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <body ng-app>
        <!--
          ddmmyyyy
          dd/mm/yyyy
          mm/dd/yyyy
          dd-mm-yyyy
          mm-dd-yyyy
          Month dd, yyyy
        -->
         <input type="date" name="bday"  ng-model="attendee.Dob" required pattern="\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}">
         <br>
         <p> Date :  {{attendee.Dob | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</p>
    </body>
```

Comment: I understand this changes the date to the correct format upon manual selection, but the datepicker still shows mm/dd/yyyy on first launch.  Someone keying in the date manually who is used to the format dd/mm/yyyy will still encounter issues.